# Using list to reference columns in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"jointid": ['ab', 'ac', 'bc'],
                "id": ['a', 'a', 'b'],
                "dog": [0, 0, 0],
                "cat": [1, 1, 1],   
                "id2": ['b', 'c', 'c'],
                "dog2": [0, 1, 1],
                "cat2": [1, 0, 0],
                "common": [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

I need to fill the common column with a dummy variable equal to 1 when both ids on the row have the same animal category animal=animal2. I use dog and cat here, but in the full data set I have 80 categories twice in each row to find these combinations. The desired output for this example is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"jointid": ['ab', 'ac', 'bc'],
                "id": ['a', 'a', 'b'],
                "dog": [0, 0, 0],
                "cat": [1, 1, 1],   
                "id2": ['b', 'c', 'c'],
                "dog2": [0, 1, 1],
                "cat2": [1, 0, 0],
                "common": [1, 0, 0]})
```

I have tried a lot of different methods, but the hang up seems to be in using the column names as list. Here's the gist of what I've been trying:

```
net = list(df.loc[:,'dog':'cat'].columns)
for x in net:    
    diff['common'] = np.where(df[x]==df[x+'2'], 1, 0)
```

Either a get a value of 1 assigned to everything or errors related to the list. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select by first an last animal, compare by convert columns to numpy array and then test if all `True`s per row by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html), here is necessary same order of animal columns:

```
mask = df.loc[:,'dog':'cat'].eq(df.loc[:,'dog2':'cat2'].to_numpy()).all(axis=1)
```

Another idea if order of columns should be different:

```
cols = ["cat", "dog"]
mask = df[cols].eq(df[pd.Index(cols) + '2'].to_numpy()).all(axis=1)
```

---

```
df['common'] = np.where(mask,1,0)
```

Alternative:

```
df['common'] = mask.view('i1')
print (df)
  jointid id  dog  cat id2  dog2  cat2  common
0      ab  a    0    1   b     0     1       1
1      ac  a    0    1   c     1     0       0
2      bc  b    0    1   c     1     0       0
```

Comment: The first version in one line worked great. What's the reasoning making it two lines by linking with mask?

Answer (score 0):

> After reading [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-not-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code/54432584#54432584) in comment, **Use methods in accepted answer**

```
df['new column name'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: 'value if condition is met' if x condition else 'value if condition is not met', axis=1)
```

in your case

```
df['common'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: 1 if x["cat"] == x["cat2"] and x["dog"] == x["dog2"] else 0, axis=1)
```

this will apply the condition across `axis=1` which means `apply function per row`

I did not see that OP has 80 categories. Though I believe you would be able to achieve it in similar fashion.

```
categories = ["cat", "dog"]
df['common'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: 1 if all([x[category] == x[category+"2"] for category in categories]) else 0, axis=1)
```

I think this is less readable than accepted answer. But it is easier to scale since you just need to add category to `categories`

Comment: Yop, I agree with last sentence, so added solution with categories too. Happy coding!